# How to create webform according to user rules

Tags: webforms

I wanted to create a "Contact Us" webform, which should have following fields-

1. Name
2. Email Address
3. Contact No
4. Message

For an anonymous user, all of these fields should display.However for logged in user, field 1, 2 and 3 should not be displayed.

I don't see any option in webform to set a filed in such a way, so that only anonymous user can see it.

I tried to create two webform and assigned different-2 submission access but unknowingly now the website is having two menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Webform Component Roles](https://drupal.org/project/webform_component_roles), this module provides a way to allow access to each webform component to only selected roles.

> This module will allow webform creators to restrict which roles can
>   use webform components per webform.

Comment: Cool.... Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Excellent. Thank you Bala.

Comment: @RaviJoshi your welcome!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

you need to try this coding

```
function _form_edit_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   
 if($form_id =='webform_form_id') {           
  //check login user enter in site
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
     $form['component_name']['#attributes']['disabled'] = true;
  }               
 }
}
```

and also you need check  **Webform Conditional module**

Comment: `Webform Component Roles` was enough for me. Thanks a lot.